# Multiple annotations found at this line: Factory bean not Found

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am building a Spring project in Spring Tool Suite(3.6.4.RELEASE).
I am trying to upgrade spring framework version from 4.0.3.RELEASE to 4.2.7.RELEASE using maven.

Before upgradation there was no error and everything running smoothly. Now project is compiling and running without error but login page is not showing and also I am getting error in my spring security configuration xml.

**Error in spring-security.xml:**
[image]

**Showing following error on STS hovering:**

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
- Factory bean 'org.springframework.security.config.http.FilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSourceParser
 $DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandlerBeanFactory' not found [config set: mcare-dashboard-web/web-context]
- Factory bean 'org.springframework.security.config.http.HttpConfigurationBuilder
 $SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilterBeanFactory' not found [config set: mcare-dashboard-web/web-context]
```

**Project Hierarchy:**

[image]

My `pom.xml` was like following:

[image]

Then I just changed the version number like this:

[image]

After that spring-security.xml was showing the error.

Can anybody explain why is this happening?

Comment: Upgrading Spring or Spring Security? Those are quite different.

Comment: Hi, do you find solution for this issue? cause I'm having the same problem

Comment: @M.Deinum, I have edited my question. I guess changing pom.xml like this, would upgrade automatically spring security as well?

Comment: Because you are using the same version property for both Spring and Spring Security. Both are different frameworks and use different versioning. Just declare 2 different properties, one for Spring and one for Spring Security.

Comment: Thank you @M.Deinum. Declaring different versioning for spring framework and spring security solved the issue.

Comment: @GustiArya , I hope above solution would solve your problem too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You state that you are upgrading Spring from version 4.0.3.RELEASE to 4.2.7.RELEASE. However effectively you are upgrading both Spring and Spring Security. This due to having a single version property, named `org.springframework-version`, to manage both the version of the Spring and Spring Security dependencies.

So changing `org.springframework-version` to `4.2.7.RELEASE` effectively upgrades Spring Security as well.

To fix this you want to have two distinct version properties one for Spring and another for Spring Security. You can than upgrade only Spring or Spring Security.